# What interprets Java's byte code

Tags: java, assembly

I was wondering if Java get's assembled and in my readings I found the compiler creates byte code which is then run on the Java Virtual Machine. Does the JVM interpret the byte code and execute it?

This is why I'm confused. Today in class the prof said "the compiler takes a high level language, creates assembly language, then the assembler takes the assembly language and creates machine language (binary) which can be run". So if Java compiles to bytecode how can it be run?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode

Comment: The JVM interprets the byte code and executes it, and/or it compiles the byte code into machine language for direct execution by the processor hardware.

Comment: Different languages... Java runs in a virtual machine, whereas native applications developed in C++ for example compile to binary and run on the real machine.

Comment: As I said below, very few modern compilers actually produce assembly language as an intermediate step.  Many will produce an optional "pseudo-assembly listing" as a means for humans to understand what the compiler is doing, but that's after the machine instructions have already been generated.  (But don't fault the prof -- he was no doubt trying to explain things as simply as possible.  Problem is, things are never that simple. ;) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of bytecode as the machine langauge of the JVM.  (Compilers don't HAVE to produce assembly code which has to be assembled, but they're a lot easier to write that way.)

Comment: That's my confusion, I thought compilers HAD to produce assembly code. Is it correct to say Java bytecode is closer to machine code than it is to object code?

So you're saying "the compiler takes a high level language, creates assembly language, then the assembler takes the assembly language and creates machine language (binary) which can be run" is not always true because the compiler may create the machine code directly?

Comment: @quest4knoledge -- Very few compilers produce assembly language as an intermediate step.  Most go directly to machine instructions (though in a "relocatable" format).  Compilers do very often have an "intermediate representations" (or several) that they compile to and then "assemble" in a sense to create the final machine instructions, but these IRs don't resemble classical assembly language to any significant degree.

Comment: And "machine code" and "object code" are two terms that are often used to mean the same thing (though no doubt someone here has some nit-picky distinction between them).

Comment: I have that nitpicky distinction in order to help keep things straight.  Object code being code that's not entirely complete, requiring linking and/or fixups during load.  Machine code being the true complete, not needing an alteration code.  Obviously both are binary programs, fully assembled.  I merely draw a distinction on the "readiness" to run as to avoid problems in discussion.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch -- Yep, that is a common distinction.  It's just that when you say "object code" you can't rely on the listener to have the same interpretation.

Answer (score 9):

There is a standard compiler setup, such as would be used for the C language, and then there is Java, which is significantly different.

The standard C compiler compiles (through several internal phases) into "machine instructions" which are directly understood by the x86 processor or whatever.

The Java compiler, on the other hand, compiles to what are sometimes called "bytecodes".  These are machine instructions, but for an imaginary machine, the Java Virtual Machine.  So the JVM interprets the bytecodes just like a "real" machine processes it's machine instructions.  (The main advantage of this is that a program compiled into bytecodes will run on *any* JVM, whether it be on an x86 system, an IBM RISC box, or the ARM processor in a Android -- so long as there's a JVM the code will run.)

(There have historically been a number of "virtual machines" similar to Java, the UCSD Pascal "P-code" system being one of the more successful ones.)

But it gets more complicated --

Interpreting "bytecodes" is fairly slow and inefficient, so most Java implementations have some sort of scheme to translate the bytecodes into "real" machine instructions.  In some cases this is done statically, in a separate compile step, but most often it's done with a "just-in-time compiler" (JITC) which converts small portions of the bytecodes to machine instructions while the application is running.  These get to be quite elaborate, with complex schemes to decide which segments of code will benefit most from translating into hardware machine instructions.  But they all, for the most part, do their magic without you needing to be aware of what's going on, and without you having to compile your Java code to target a specific type of processor.

Answer (score 1):

Just a clarifying note:
That which in java is called "bytecode" is what in your original description is "creates machine language (binary) which can be run"

So the answer to how to run java bytecode is:
You build a processor which can handle java bytecode, in the same way that if you want to execute normal x86 code you build a cpu to handle that.

Javas binary machine language is not really different from the binary instruction format of other cpus such as x86 or powerpc. And there do exists cpus which can execute java bytecode directly. (That would be a normal Intel/Amd cpu).

An other example: How would you run powerpc code, on a normal intel cpu? You would build a piece of software which would at runtime translate the powerpc binary code, to x86 code. The case for java is not really that different. So to run java code on a x86 cpu, you need a program  which translate the java binary code(aka the bytecode) to x86 binary code. This is what the jvm* does. And it does this either by interpreting the java instructions one at a time, or by translating a huge chunk of instructions at a time(Called jit). Exactly how the jvm handles the translation depend on which jvm implementation you use and its settings.(There are multiple independent implementations of java jvms which implement their translation in different ways).

But there is one thing which make java a bit different. Unlike other binary instruction formats such as x86, java was newer really designed to run directly on a cpu. Its binary format is designed in a way which make it easy to translate it to binary code for "normal" cpus such as x86 or powerpc.

*The jvm does in fact handle more then just translating the java binary code to processor dependend code. It also handles memory allocations for java programs, and it handles communication between a java program, and the users operation system. This is done to make the java program relative independent of the users operation system and platform details.

Answer (score 0):

In a short explanation: The JVM translates the Java Byte Code into machine specific code. The generated machine specific code is then executed by the machine.

The Java compiler translates JAVA into ByteCode. The JVM translates ByteCode into Assembly (machine specific code) at runtime. The machine executes the Assembly.

Comment: The JVM does not, initially, convert bytecodes to machine code.  Initially it interprets, and only "hot" code is run through the JITC to produce machine code.

Comment: If a program is written in assembly must it be put through an assembler before it can run on the machine? Is object code the same as assembly code?

Comment: @quest4knoledge -- There actually are assemblers for Java bytecodes (though they aren't used when compiling and executing standard Java -- they're more for hackers and system test folks).  And "object code" means different things to different people -- one interpretation would make it the same as "machine instructions".  A (only) slightly different interpretation is that "object code" refers to the relocatable and possibly bindable representation of machine instructions that resides in an "object program" file.